# System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type "aspnet_isapi.dll" - how to fix?

Tags: iis, iis-7, httphandler

When accessing the handler in IIS7 I get the following error:

> System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll'

What can cause this and how can it be resolved?

Thanks